# How to solve a differentiation problem

Tags: calculus

> Say $f: I ⊆R \rightarrow R$ differentiable in $c∈ I$. Prove the following:
>
> $\forall\epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0/ c-\delta<u ≤c ≤v<\delta+c \longrightarrow |f(v)-f(u)-(v-u)f'(c)|<\epsilon(v-u)$

I only know for a fact that $f$ is continuous in $c$, i.e.

$\forall\epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0/ |x-c|<\rightarrow |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable at $c$ then you have that

$$\forall \epsilon > 0,\, \exists \delta > 0,\,
\forall x\neq c \,\text{ in }\, I\cap(c-\delta, c+\delta),\,\\
\left| \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c} - f'(c)
\right|< \epsilon
\iff
|f(x) - f(c) - (x-c)\,f'(c)| < \epsilon |x-c|.
\tag{$*$}
$$

Now, observe that

\begin{align}
|f(v)-f(u)-(v-u)f'(c)|
&=
\left|\Big(f(v)-f(x)-(v-x)f'(c)\Big) - \Big(f(u)-f(x)-(u-x)f'(c)\Big)\right|
\\&\leqslant
\left|f(v)-f(x)-(v-x)f'(c)\right| + \left|f(u)-f(x)-(u-x)f'(c)\right|.
\end{align}

Hence, given $\epsilon > 0$ we can take $\epsilon/2$ in $(*)$ to obtain some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $c-\delta < u < c < v < c+\delta$, then

\begin{align}
|f(v)-f(u)-(v-u)f'(c)|
&<
\epsilon |v-x| + \epsilon |u-x|
\\&=
\epsilon (v-x) + \epsilon (x-u)
=
\epsilon (v-u)
\end{align}